# Strange behavior with ASLR and VirtualAlloc

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi

My issue is that I try to allocate memory to an application(x86) that I made (with ASLR disabled via the Linker) like this:

```
void* space = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, LPVOID(0x400000),
    0x20000, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

and the return value of `VirtualAllocEx` was `NULL` (0). As you can see, what I tried is to allocate space in the address space 0x400000 which is the default virtual address space of the executable. Now the weird thing is that this memory allocation works with ASLR, but it does not work with ASLR disabled.

So my question is this: Why this is happening ? I mean, why ASLR gives you the ability to allocate space in such a "critical" address ? And also, why this memory allocation fails without ASLR ? Doesn't this possess a security threat for modern systems ?

Comment: So what does `GetLastError` return? Maybe when ASLR is enabled this address is not special anymore and is not used while without ASLR it is already used for something?

Comment: *"why ASLR gives you the ability to allocate space in such a "critical" address"* - Because, with ASLR, that space stops being special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ASLR disabled, your *code* will be at address 0x400000 so the allocation will fail.

With ASLR enabled, your code could be anywhere so this code will work sometimes (possibly most times) but sometimes fail apparently at random, which is worse.

Solution: pass `lpAddress` as NULL, let the system decide where the allocation should go.  Why would you want to do anything else?

Please note that, from a security viewpoint (or indeed any other, really), there is nothing special about address 0x400000. It's just that Windows happens to base your code there with ASLR disabled.

Comment: The OP isn't looking for a solution. They are asking about some weird security implications. Might want to address that.

Comment: @IInspectable Um, OK.  Address, lol.  OP, what security threat did you think being able to allocate memory at 0x400000 might pose?  As has already been commented above, there is nothing special about this address - at all, actually.  It's just that Windows _happens_ to base your code there with ASLR disabled.

Comment: Oh my God. I didn't thought that the code worked just because ASLR rebased PE into another place, as is supposed to do anyway. I thought that there was a property of ASLR that did this, but things were much simpler. I thank you both you and @Anders . I will accept your solution because it was posted earlier than the one from Anders, but both answers really helped me! I up-voted both of you :)

Comment: @GeorgeBishop Picking one answer over another because of a 10 minute time difference is silly. I don't care about the reputation points but you should pick the best answer, not the first answer. A month or a year from now the time difference does not matter at all, the point of StackOverflow is to get the **best** answer on top. The best answer might even vary over time, somebody could post an even better answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

With ASLR enabled it might work most of the time but in theory it could use 0x400000 as its random base. When ASLR is disabled it is likely that the EXE has been loaded there so you cannot allocate new memory at the same address.

0x400000 is not a critical address and has no special meaning to Windows. The EXE PE header specifies the address and the Microsoft toolchain uses 0x400000 as the default for x86 EXE files. The Microsoft linker for ARM64 forces you to use a different address, above 4 GiB.

Comment: 0x400000 might not be the default base address for x64 apps, either.  I don't actually know, I've never checked.

Comment: @PaulSanders: The default preferred load address for a 64-bit executable is 0x100000000.

Comment: @PaulSanders The AMD64 linker lets you use 0x400000 if you want, the ARM64 linker does not.